# Why do you want to maximise the entropy when deriving Boltzmann's distribution?

Tags: entropy

I am sure this has a simple answer, but I can't seem to get my head around in at the moment. I am going through the derivation of the Boltzmann distribution through maximising entropy through the constraints that the probability sum to 1 and the average energy is constant. However, why do you want to maximise entropy to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a basic assumption of statistical physics that the probability distribution ${p_k}$ for microstates $k$ best to use for a system with internal energy $U$ is that which obeys the constraint

$$
\sum_k p_k E_k = U
$$
where $E_k$ is energy of microstate $k$.

There is another constraint 
$$
\sum_k p_k = 1.
$$
There are many different distributions obeying these constraints.

It can be shown in different ways that the best distribution to use in this situation is that which maximizes *information entropy functional*

$$
I[{p_k}] = \sum_k -p_k \ln p_k.
$$
This is purely mathematical function of probabilities - a different concept from thermodynamic entropy.

**Why the function to be maximized is the one above and not some other one?**

There are more ways to arrive at this. Here is one.

For given set ${p_k}$, imagine ensemble of many ($N$) identical systems in an ensemble state where relative frequency of the system in microstate $k$ is close to ${p_k}$.

There are many (W) such ensemble states. We *assume* that the best distribution ${p_k}$ to use for a single system is that which maximizes this number and obeys the additional constraint above.

It can be shown that

$$
W \approx e^{NI[{p_k}]}
$$
(the error is negligible if all $Np_k$ are much greater than 1). Hence the ${p_k}$ that maximizes $W$ maximizes also $I$.

For another and more detailed explanation, see for example

Jaynes, E. T., 1963, *Information Theory and Statistical Mechanics*, in Statistical Physics, K. Ford (ed.), Benjamin, New York, p. 181:

http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/brandeis.pdf